# jQuery: Hide | Show 5 columns onclick (and put the last 4 columns to 100% width)

Tags: jquery, onclick

New to jQuery and haven't programmed in several years. Frankly, I'm ok with HTML and CSS, but terrible at scripting.

I'm trying to find a script that will collapse the first 5 columns of a 9 column table, and while doing so, stretch out the last 4 columns to 100% width. So text that says "Hide columns" when showing and says "Show columns" while hidden. When the first 5 columns are collapsed, the remainder of the table spreads out across the page, and of course reverts to original state when the hidden columns are unhidden again by clicking "Show columns".

I've found lots of scripts that will hide columns by various ways of selection, but I'm hoping to have single click solution to hide/show those first 5 columns. And I've seen no way to stretch the remainder columns to 100% width.

Can someone offer some help here, please?

Merci:)
Shawn

```
<tr class="parent">
        <th width="2%"><div align="center">Eon</div></th>
        <th width="2%"><div align="center">Era</div></th>
        <th width="2%"><div align="center">Period</div></th>
        <th width="2%"><div align="center">Epoch</div></th>
        <th width="2%"><div align="center">Ma</div></th>
        <th width="12%"><div align="center">Descent of Man</div></th>
        <th width="16%"><div align="center">Distinction/Morphology</div></th>
        <th width="16%"><div align="center">Example (species)</div></th>
        <th width="16%"><div align="center">Divergant</div></th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="parent">
        <td class="blackborder">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="blackborder">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="blackborder">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="blackborder">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="blackborder">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="blackborder">Superdomain Neomura</td>
        <td class="blackborder">&nbsp;</td>
       <td class="blackborder"> <a href onclick="TINY.box.show({url:'test-advanced.html',width:300,height:150})">Ajax, Advanced Functions</a></td>
        <td class="blackborder">The clade Life is divided into the following clades: Domain <span class="domain-text">Bacteria</span>, Superdomain Neomura</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="parent">
        <td class="blackborder">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="blackborder">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="blackborder">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="blackborder">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="blackborder">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="clade-marker">Domain <span class="domain-text">Eukaryota</span></td>
        <td class="blackborder">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="blackborder">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="blackborder">The superdomain Neomura is divided into the following clades: Domain Archaea, Domain Eukaryota</td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: Any html/script to show?

Comment: Sure. As you can see, the first 5 columns are all about geological time, then the last 4 columns are the 'meat'. I will have a lot of information in the last 4 columns so sometimes it might be better to collapse the geological stuff:

Answer (score 0):

According to the HTML in the question, you could use something like this:

```
  $('.parent').each(function(){
      var i = 0;
      while(i < 5){
          $(this).find('td, th').eq(i).hide();
          i++;
      }                
  });
```

OR:

```
  var arr = [0,1,2,3,4];
  $("td, th").filter(function(){
       return arr.indexOf($(this).index()) > -1;
  }).hide();
```

When the 5 columns are hidden, they do not take any space in the table, so the rest of the collumns will use all available space.

And extended example here (with toggle button) - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/30c6emyL/)

Comment: I'm not sure how to approve an answer, but your answer definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

A less mathematical approach would be to add hide/show classes to any rows you want to expand. The alternative gets ugly once you need to remove a non-sequential number of rows.

```
$(document).on('click', '.hide-button', function() {
  $(".hide").hide();
  $(".expand").width("25%");
});

$(document).on('click', '.show', function() {
  $(".hide").show(); 
  $(".expand").width("2%");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0zsorp74/)

Comment: By non-sequential you mean columns 1,2,3,4,8,11 for example, yes?

Comment: So if all geological columns were affiliated with "geo" class and all biota with "biota" the sequence of columns wouldn't matter. Is that correct?